# Dependencies in RequireJS with Backbone, Underscore, and jQuery in 2014

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

I have seen a lot of questions regarding using RequireJS w/ Backbone, Underscore, and jQuery. My question is slightly different; my app works, but I don't know why.

Currently, Underscore, jQuery, and Backbone all export AMD modules, so there is no need for me to shim them and export their variables anymore. Therefore, my `main.js` looks like the following code snippet.

**main.js**

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2',
        'jquery-ui': 'lib/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min',
        underscore: 'lib/underscore/underscore.min',
        backbone: 'lib/backbone/backbone.min',
        'backbone.localStorage': 'lib/backbone/backbone.localStorage'
    }
});

require(['jquery', 'jquery-ui', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'backbone.localStorage'], function() {

});
```

**require.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Sample Project</title>
        <!-- data-main attribute tells require.js to load
             scripts/main.js after require.js loads. -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My Sample Project</h1>
        <div id="test"> </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" data-main="js/main" src="js/lib/require/require.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I go to `require.html`, I can go to console and all my variables are there correctly loaded. For example, `var x = Backbone.Model.extend({}); var y = new x;` works just fine. However, Backbone depends on both Underscore and jQuery. Does RequireJS automatically resolve these dependencies using the modules supplied by these library, or is it only working as a fluke?

Comment: The libraries `define` their dependencies themselves. Have a look at the (uncompressed) code of Backbone or jQuery and search for `define(`, that should get you to the right line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `require` right after requirejs config setup

```
require(['jquery', 'jquery-ui', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'backbone.localStorage'], function() {

});
```

They loaded in the correct order **by a chance**, to control that sequence you need to **define dependencies of each module** in a shim

Comment: I know my module requires them; I'm asking if they loaded in the correct order by chance or if RequireJS organized them in the correct way.

Comment: Wrong. The factory method of each module (library) will set the appropriate global before your callback executes. It's better to use each AMD-compliant library's return value in your callback (or factory method in the case of your own module) in case the global value changes or disappears. Each one of those won't be satisfied until its dependencies are satisfied.

Comment: What is wrong? The question is about downloading order if there is no shim that controls dependencies, all this stuff happens before actual module callback is called.

Answer (score 0):

Require helps a lot with this kind of work.

You can specify dependencies in a easy and correct way usim 'shim' command like this.

```
//Coffeescript example
paths:
    backbone : 'path/backbone'
    underscore : 'path/underscore'
    jquery: 'path/jquery'


 shim:
    backbone:
        deps:['underscore','jquery']
        exports: 'Backbone'
```

This way you define that when a module called 'Backbone' was called, require will load all the dependencies written inside deps:[].
Now it will never load backbone before underscore.

I have a blog and a post about it, unfortunately it's only in portuguese, but maybe helps.

http://www.rcarvalhojs.com/backbone/2014/06/03/comecando-require-backbone.html

Comment: Chrome translated it for me and it helped a bit. I get that we can specify dependencies, but what I'm asking is that I didn't specify my dependencies and my app still worked, so I'm asking if that was magic that they all loaded in the correct order or since they are AMDs, RequireJS took care of the load order?